# Prevent scroll from jumping up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have implemented endless scrolling for showing posts.
After I stop scrolling after say 100 items, item number 98 is visible in viewport.
But, after images from upper items are loaded they push all subsequent posts down.
Because scrollTop is preserved and 98 item's offsetTop is bigger than when I stoped scrolling, it looks like whole content is scrolled up.

Basically, I would like to freeze scroll so that displayed items stay same as when I stopped scrolling.
Of course, user should be able to continue scrolling.

Comment: set a jsfiddle please

Comment: not enough info, could you please post some code, Or as @roasted said a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to assign a `width` and `height` to your images? In this case, the browser displays a placeholder for the image and the content doesn't jump around.

Comment: This isn't an option. I use rss feeds and not every image has width and height set. I tried with image preloading and displaying post only when every image get it's width and height set, but it's taking to long to get that information.